# Configuring MariaDB XA Driver in JBoss 6

Tags: configuration, jboss, mariadb, jboss6.x, xa

I am having following issue with mariaDB jar

```
12:42:54,194 ERROR [org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.XAResourceRecoveryImpl] (Periodic Recovery) IJ000906: Error during crash recovery: java:jboss/datasources/myDS (Could not create connection): javax.resource.ResourceException: Could not create connection
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory.getXAManagedConnection(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:525)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory$1.run(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:416)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory$1.run(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:413)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
        at javax.security.auth.Subject.doAs(Subject.java:422) [rt.jar:1.8.0_45]
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory.createManagedConnection(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:412)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.XAResourceRecoveryImpl.open(XAResourceRecoveryImpl.java:343)
        at org.jboss.jca.core.tx.jbossts.XAResourceRecoveryImpl.getXAResources(XAResourceRecoveryImpl.java:170)
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jbossatx.jta.XAResourceRecoveryHelperWrapper.getXAResources(XAResourceRecoveryHelperWrapper.java:51) [jbossjts-integration-4.17.29.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.17.29.Final-redhat-1 (revision: ede35097ddd6c0f539ba06e78df7794c0e06d68d)]
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.resourceInitiatedRecoveryForRecoveryHelpers(XARecoveryModule.java:510) [jbossjts-jacorb-4.17.29.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.17.29.Final-redhat-1]
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.jta.recovery.arjunacore.XARecoveryModule.periodicWorkFirstPass(XARecoveryModule.java:176) [jbossjts-jacorb-4.17.29.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.17.29.Final-redhat-1]
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.doWorkInternal(PeriodicRecovery.java:747) [jbossjts-jacorb-4.17.29.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.17.29.Final-redhat-1]
        at com.arjuna.ats.internal.arjuna.recovery.PeriodicRecovery.run(PeriodicRecovery.java:375) [jbossjts-jacorb-4.17.29.Final-redhat-1.jar:4.17.29.Final-redhat-1]
Caused by: java.lang.ClassCastException: org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver cannot be cast to javax.sql.XADataSource
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory.getXADataSource(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:647)
        at org.jboss.jca.adapters.jdbc.xa.XAManagedConnectionFactory.getXAManagedConnection(XAManagedConnectionFactory.java:508)
        ... 12 more
```

I downloaded mariadb-java-client-1.1.9 from mariadb website and create following module.xml file which is placed in jboss_home\modules\org\mariadb\main

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>  
<module xmlns="urn:jboss:module:1.0" name="org.mariadb">
  <resources>
  <resource-root path="mariadb-java-client-1.1.9.jar"/>
  </resources>
  <dependencies>
  <module name="javax.api"/>
  <module name="javax.transaction.api"/>
  </dependencies>  
</module>
```

Here is my standalone.xml

```
<datasources>
            <datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/rDS" pool-name="rDS" enabled="true">
                <connection-url>jdbc:mariadb://localhost:3306/soccer</connection-url>
                <driver>mariadb</driver>
                <pool>
                    <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                </pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>user_name</user-name>
                    <password>my_password</password>
                </security>
                <statement>
                    <prepared-statement-cache-size>100</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                    <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                </statement>
            </datasource>
            <xa-datasource jndi-name="java:jboss/datasources/myDS" pool-name="myDS" enabled="true">
                <xa-datasource-property name="ServerName">
                    localhost
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-property name="PortNumber">
                    3306
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <xa-datasource-property name="DatabaseName">
                    soccer
                </xa-datasource-property>
                <driver>mariadb</driver>
                <xa-pool>
                    <min-pool-size>1</min-pool-size>
                    <max-pool-size>100</max-pool-size>
                </xa-pool>
                <security>
                    <user-name>user_name</user-name>
                    <password>my_password</password>
                </security>
                <statement>
                    <prepared-statement-cache-size>100</prepared-statement-cache-size>
                    <share-prepared-statements>false</share-prepared-statements>
                </statement>
            </xa-datasource>
            <drivers>
                <driver name="mariadb" module="org.mariadb">
                    <xa-datasource-class>org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver</xa-datasource-class>
                </driver>
            </drivers>
        </datasources>
```

Thanks

Answer (score 5):

The org.mariadb.jdbc.Driver does not implement the javax.sql.XADataSource.
Please change your DS to org.mariadb.jdbc.MySQLDataSource and it will work.